# Add all tool parameters at once

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, parameters

If I put a new tool into the ModelBuilder in ArcGIS I often want to add all tool parameters as variables at once instead of clicking them one by one.

Am I missing something or is this an issue we've got to live with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're referring specifically to the tool right click > **make variable** > **from parameter** > **X**, then no, there is no way to expose them all at once. You need to do them one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If it is the same few tools that you are using over and over, make a model that has these tools with parameters as variables, and save into your custom toolbox.

Then, when you are building new models, open this model and then copy and paste those tools between windows.